# how to xml to string in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

i've done this in java and it's done in almost 20 rows, but copying it in android it seems not to work. I've just to read two string from a XML file and save them in a String[]. Do i have to use "XmlPullParser" or there's a faster way?

EDIT: i'd love to try your solutions but i'm stuck with a silly problem. I've put the xml file under "res/xml_file/myFile.xml" , how do i get the path information?

Answer (score 2):

Android developers recommend XmlPullParser

> We recommend XmlPullParser, which is an efficient and maintainable way to parse XML on Android.Historically Android has had two implementations of this interface:

- KXmlParser via XmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser()
- ExpatPullParser, via Xml.newPullParser()

Either choice is fine.

Here you have more info and examples: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

Personally I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) is the faster way.
You can access your xml [Element](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) value with `getTextContent()` method.

This snippet assumes that Element you are looking for is a single entry

```
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(inputstream);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
        String value = ((Element) nodes.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("tagname").item(0).getTextContent();
    }catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```